# Probability distribution of three random variables

Tags: probability, coverage-probability

The following formula is a formula I got from a [paper](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00360800/PDF/opploha3.pdf) that deals with wireless networks specifically when calculating coverage probabilities, it is powerful because one can use it for general distributions.

$$\mathbb{P}[ X \geq T( Y+Z )] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathcal{L}_{X}(-2i \pi s)-1}{2i\pi s} \times \mathcal{L}_Y(2i \pi Ts)\times \mathcal{L}_Z(2i \pi Ts)\ ds$$

where $X,Y,Z$ are random variables and $\mathcal{L}$ is the laplace transform while $T$ is a positive constant.

Assume the above formula is correct, I would like to use the above formula for a specific example $$X\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(m,\theta)$$

$$Y= 0$$
$$ Z = 10^{-11}$$

I solve it the following way,

$$\mathcal{L}_X(s)=(1+s\ \theta)^{-m}$$ 
$$\mathcal{L}_Y(s)=1$$
$$\mathcal{L}_Z(s)= \mathbb{E}(e^{-s 10^{-11}})= e^{-s 10^{-11}}$$

Then basically substitute $s$ by $-2i\pi s$ for the first Laplace (laplace of $X$), and $2i\pi Ts$ for the other two.. i.e

$$\mathcal{L}_X(-2i\pi s)=(1-2i\pi s\theta)^m$$ 
$$\mathcal{L}_Y(2i\pi Ts)=1$$
$$\mathcal{L}_Z(2i\pi Ts)= e^{-2i\pi Ts 10^{-11}}$$

Am I doing things correct here? Can you find any mistake with my strategy?

Do you think when integrating numerically this expression using any computer program, I should add the absolute (magnitude) of the above expression or should it be left as imaginary?

The reason I ask this question is because I try to simulate using MATLAB a specific example and I get no result.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi @Xi'an ofcourse, this is the link https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00360800/PDF/opploha3.pdf and the  formula I am using is on page 5 of this paper.

Comment: [Also asked on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038827/15941) where the OP is now offering a 50-point reputation bounty for an answer.

Comment: i think its not against the rules if it is i can delete one of them @dilipsarwate

Comment: @DilipSarwate You can really be helpful by explaining if this is against the rules or not, not by just stating the fact that you noticed it was duplicated.

Comment: @Xi'an was the paper useful to you? Thanks alot.

Comment: @xi'an oh ok. thanks for the clarification. Do you happen to have an idea whether the strategy is correct?

Comment: Without getting into the relevant paper, I cannot tell. It simply seems odd to me that you would apply a formula designed for random variables to a deterministic lower bound.

Comment: @xi'an assuming the lower bound is random variable forx example $Y$ is uniformly distributed then does the strategy hold? i.e the logic of my answer is it correct?

Comment: @xi'an to make it even clearer, I have defined the $Y$ to be deterministic but really I also have $Y$ random variable i just made it simpler in my question for the readers